# How to charge credit card AND set up automated recurring billing in one step with Authorize.Net

Tags: payment, authorize.net, payment-processing, recurring-billing

I’m integrating authorize.net into my web application. I’ve used the direct post method (DPM)to charge the account initially.  However, for each transaction I also need to set up automated reoccurring billing. How would I go about doing this without asking for the information again, particularly when after DPM posts the initial transaction, the credit card data is no longer available?

I also would like to get the status of each reoccurring transaction so it can be confirmed and followed up on if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that with DPM as it takes the user's credit card information off of your website so you don't have access to it. If you want to make an initial payment and then use ARB to create a subscription you need to use AIM with ARB.

Comment: Just to confirm, AIM being the method hosted by Authorize.Net? If so, how would you do it then, without having the credit card enter your system? I'm a bit worried about security.

Comment: Yes. I do mean their Advanced Integration Method API.

Comment: From what I can tell, the difference between AIM and DPM is the payment data is posted back to your site instead of Auth.Net. You then invoke Auth.Net APIs to process the transaction. Correct? The only concern I have is having the credit card data in my possession for the duration of the transaction (a few seconds). Do you have any suggestions from a PCI/DSS perspective on best method to handle the credit card data during that short period?

Comment: What about CIM? Can I create a profile, then charge it immediately? Can this be done while using my own web page or do I have to use the hosted option?

Comment: You can use CIM to create a profile and then charge it immediately. You can use either the API or hosted version as both essentially do the same thing. I have not played with the hosted version yet so I am unsure how to best use it but if you use CIM you should be able to accomplish your goal of having a one-step process for making payments and setting up a subscription. The only catch is you will need to write your own subscription engine as CIM does not offer recurring billing as a feature regardless of which version you use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ARB interface in order to do recurring transactions but there are a lot of problems with it, like lack of support (send an email and wait a couple of weeks for a non-helpful response for example) and weak documentation.

Documentation for SOAP interface for Authorize.net ARB:
http://www.authorize.net/support/ARB_SOAP_guide.pdf

And for the XMl interface:
http://www.authorize.net/support/ARB_guide.pdf

ARB programming documentation:
http://developer.authorize.net/api/arb/

I just switched off of Authorize.net to USAEPAY.  Here are some reasons why:
1. When you use Authorize.net ARB, your customer comes on the site to sign up, and you send the ARB request to create the subscription and you get back a success code so you give the user the subscription.  Then later that night they actually try to collect the first payment and a lot of times this fails, so you get a spreadsheet emailed to you the next day about the problem.  This is terrible because now you lost the opportunity to say to the customer at sign up time that the card is declined.  Goodbye sale!
2.  I don't know if they added this recently but they didn't have a way to verify if a customer's credit card is still valid.  Imagine 3 months into a subscription the card is over the limit, or cancelled, or expired etc.  You don't know so how do you prompt the customer to put in a new card?  You just stop getting paid, unless you want to manually open these spreadsheets and start emailing customers.  YUCK.

USAEPAY works much better, the API is easier, its much better documented and you get email responses in 1-2 days and its less expensive. For example, you can query USAEPAY to get a list of successful payments, and verify that you shouldn't deactivate the account for non-payment:
http://wiki.usaepay.com/developer/soap-1.4/methods/getcustomerreport

Before you go too far with AuthNet I highly encourage you to save yourself a lot of pain and contact FranchisePaymentNetwork (FPN) to get set up with USAEpay.

They can even POST BACK to your website to let you know if a transaction is successful or not for recurring billing transactions and you can query it to verify that customer payments are getting collected so you know if you should expire an account or not.

I am not affiliated with USAEpay or Franchise Payment Network except as a satisfied paying customer / consumer of their services.

Comment: FYI, Authnet also has "post back" capability. It's called [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/). Also, based on your answer, it's apparent you didn't implement their APIs very well if you set your subscriptions to start the same night you set it up. You're not supposed to do that. You're supposed to use AIM to charge the first payment and then use ARB for all recurring payments. As far as integrations go Authorize.Net is easiest by far. You'll be hard pressed to find an experienced ecommerce developer who says otherwise.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use the web interface to set up recurring billing subscriptions. Their API works perfectly fine. Plus their [support forums](http://community.developer.authorize.net/) are a great place to get help with issues.

Comment: Yet more, there is no way to tell if a credit card is valid at some date in the future. No company is psychic and can tell you this. The odds of a future subscription payment failing is the same no matter who you use for your payment gateway. You can also automated the contacting for failed payments if you use Silent Post. In fact, a well built website or application will do this.

Comment: So pretty much I disagree with everything you said.

Comment: 1. John, I'm not stating you need to use the web interface to set up ARB.  I only referred to using the API for this.  2. If you need to use AIM first before using ARB, that's very confusing and confirms my point about poor documentation, plus auth net doesn't explain this when you ask them about it.  3. You misunderstand my point about expired cards.  My point is its hard to detect when you're no longer collecting payment.  I know many experienced eCommerce developers who don't like Authorize.net so I'm not hard pressed on this. Even the link you gave to silent post complains about docs.

Comment: As for point #2, Authnet shouldn't have to tell a developer how to build their application. They only need to go as far as documenting their APIs. If a developer doesn't know how to use them they should refer it to someone with more experience. As for point #3, Silent Post takes care of that completely. You're notified immediately if a payment fails.

Comment: I respectfully completely disagree on your position about documentation and I stand by my opinion that Authorize.net is a pain in the neck and that superior (and less expensive and better documented and supported) alternatives exist like USAEPAY which deserve consideration.